# Mapquest 'community license' service discontinuation terms?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, license, mapquest

I want to use MapQuest's geocoding services under their Community License: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/terms-of-use

I can't find the clause that explains under what terms I can discontinue using their service (and ofcourse, unsubscribe to their license).

Can I choose to terminate using their service at any time and will their license no longer apply to the app?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Versions of the Community License

**COMMUNITY EDITION (Licensed Data)**

A popular free option among developers, the Community Edition using Licensed Data offers an industry-leading platform that includes the developer tools and resources needed to build rich and engaging mapping applications. General restrictions and requirements regarding the use of the MapQuest Platform are outlined in the [Terms of Use.](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/terms-of-use)

**COMMUNITY EDITION (Open Data)**

The use of MapQuest's Open Data APIs and Web Services is only available as a Community Edition as it relies heavily on third party services such as OpenStreetMap (OSM). However, the flexibility of Open Data is far greater than its Licensed Data counterpart as there are no transactional limitations which makes for an attractive option for developers. Please see the [Community Edition Terms of Use](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/terms-of-use) for further details.

Your best (free) option is the Open Data version where there is no obligation to 'dis-continue' (or stop) using the service.

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/terms-overview